# Bound on probabilities

Tags: probability

Let $p_n$ be a set of probabilities so that $\sum_{n=1}^N p_n = 1$.

I believe that the following should hold:
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{n=1}^N p_n^{\frac{k-2}{k-1}} \right)^{k-1}\leq N
\end{align}
for $k \geq 2$, with equality if $p_n = 1/N$. What is the easiest way to show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way, using Jensen's inequality:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N p_n^{\frac{k-2}{k-1}}
= N \cdot \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N p_n^{\frac{k-2}{k-1}}
\leq N \cdot \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N p_n \right)^{\frac{k-2}{k-1}}
= N^{\frac{1}{k-1}}
$$
using that the function $x\mapsto x^{\frac{k-2}{k-1}}$ is concave.

In general, convexity/concavity+Jensen, Cauchy-Schwarz (or Hölder), and monotonicity of $\ell_p$ norms will get you a long way.